# how to import pictures into app from backup of db

Tags: java, android, android-file

I took the backup of my sqlite db and even i took backup of my pics which i captured through app and those images are stored in root directory..Now i imported my db but i don't know how to import pics ..Please help me to import pics in my app ..I have stored images in the name  CAT_IMG.Here zipped when exported and unzipped when i import..i unzipped the images..Help me to import

```
 public void backup() throws IOException {
        File direct = new File(getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG");

        System.out.println("LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL"+direct);
        File backupDirect = new File(root + "/instinctcoder"+"/zipunzip"+"/data");

        System.out.println("PPPPPPPP"+backupDirect);
        for(File srcFile : direct.listFiles()) {
            if (srcFile.isFile() && srcFile.getName().endsWith(".JPG")) {
                String targetFile = backupDirect.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + srcFile.getName();
                copyFile(srcFile, targetFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(File src, String dest) throws IOException {
        FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
        FileChannel destChannel = null;
        try {
            sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
            destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
            destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sourceChannel.close();
            destChannel.close();
        }



    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by import into app ? need some more info.

Comment: export in the sense taking the backup of db.And even if the app cache is cleared when i click import button all my app data should be imported into my app.